# How to enable the DIV instruction in ASM output of C compiler

Tags: c, assembly, division, 68000

I am using vbcc compiler to translate my C code into Motorola 68000 ASM.

For whatever reason, every time I use the division (just integer, not floats) in code, the compiler only inserts the following stub into the ASM output (that I get generated upon every recompile):

```
public  __ldivs
jsr __ldivs
```

I explicitly searched for all variations of DIVS/DIVU, but every single time, there is just that stub above. The code itself works (I debugged it on target device), so the final code does have the DIV instruction, just not the intermediate output.

Since this is the most expensive instruction and it's in an inner loop, I really gotta experiment with tweaking the code to get the max performance of it.

However, I can't do it if I don't see the resulting ASM code. Any ideas how to enable it ? The compiler manual does not specify anything like that, so there must clearly must be some other - probably common - higher principle in play ?

Comment: This stub is actually a call to a function called __ldivs . Most likely it is part of your C runtime library. You'd probably want to disassemble the __ldivs function to see how it performs the calculation.

Comment: What types do the opearns and result have? The 68000 does not have a full 32 bit division. Show a [mcve]

Comment: @MichaelPetch Well, the problem with the C runtime lib is, I don't really have one - e.g. I do not have access to heap / floats / memcpy or anything like that - just the basic language set. Perhaps the platform does have some minimal runtime. Let me check the libraries it is linked against. I went through the 300k lines of the ASM output and made sure the __ldivs is not there.

Comment: You are probably linking against some form of math library.

Comment: @Olaf : The types are short int (e.g. 16 bit on the platform) - all related instructions have .W modifier. Though sometimes the compiler inserts .L, to my huge disappointment, as 68000 is just 16-bit. While off-topic - any idea why that happens ?

Comment: No, sorry. As I wrote, post all relevant information, not just a description. I did not program the 68000 in C, just Assembler and avoided `DIV` for performance reasons like hell. Check the options; perhaps this is some generic 680x0 code (the 68020+ had a full set of integer division, IIRC, so this might just link the appropriate lib)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: While I do not see any specific library in the linker section of the makefile, it is a good hint, as I was only checking the docs on compiler (not linker, which is a separate binary in itself and there might be more hints on the runtime library). As for the math library, to get floats, I'd have to link against mieee.lib, which resulted in issues, so I reworked algorithms to just use integers.

Comment: Can you add an example of C code that the compiler compiles into a call to __ldivs, instead of using DIV instruction as you expect ? However did you try to cast the operand to uint16_t or int16_t, and also to cast the result of the division, in order to 'help' the compiler to choose the DIV instruction ?

Comment: Post the options you pass to gcc for compilation.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: So, there is an runtime library in *.A format. it has 8 KB and I can see the __ldivs in the text header section. Now I just need a 68k disassembler. Will go google one, but if you guys have suggestions, I'm open :-)

Comment: @Olaf It's not gcc. It's vbcc, but the options are: -k -c99 -O2 -c -o

Comment: @Laurent This compiler does not handle casting very well - it generates awful amount of 68k instructions if you do. I found it's fastest to just make sure one does not mix&match various types - especially singed and unsigned together (if possible, of course = sometimes you do need negative numbers).

Comment: Anyway, you are still lacking a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf Well, at this point we already know that the compiler/linker handles division via the runtime C library (weird, as multiplication instructions are inserted to ASM just fine), so the code examples are not really needed, as it's not my code that is doing anything. I just downloaded a linker documentation and am going through it to see if it's even possible to configure linker to avoid the heavy jsr/rts run-time cost, which basically throws every single division over 200 cycle barrier - slow enough to consider a huge LUT...

Comment: Statements comtaining something like "we already know" are most times not true. **We** do not; know, it is just you assuming. But as you refuse to post allinformation, I wonder why you have asked in the first place, as you apparently knew the "answer" already. Thanks for wasting our time.

Comment: @Olaf Wow, slow down turbo :-) Quite a few assumptions you got there ! I had no idea why the compiler inserted a call to C library for something that should be 1 DIV instruction. From your initial description it looked like you need 3 separate code examples, but now that I am reading that link you posted, it looks like one is enough. Had I known that before, I'd post the C code too - it's basically 1 line : Slope1 = AbsX / Pairs;

Comment: @3DCoder doesn't vbcc support inline assembly? If this is such a critical code path then it seems like this is the book case scenario for using it (along with conditional compilation if you need to support different architectures with the same code).

Comment: `l` in `__ldivs` seems to stand for `long`, `s` for `signed`. Somehow the compiler is convinced that the 16 bit version doesn't suffice. One possibility is that `-32768/-1` overflows `divs` but C standard requires to return 32768, hence the compiler decides to deprecate `divs`.

Comment: @EliAlgranti I have not tried the inline asm under vbcc yet, but from the docs it looks (of course, i could be wrong) it's supposed to work only on whole methods. I'm currently on 4th refactored version (changing algorithms, approaches). Only the fastest one will be written in hand-optimized ASM, so for the time being, C must be used - I think you'll agree that for quick high-level coding, C does beat ASM.

Comment: @user3528438 That is correct. Yesterday evening, when I was browsing the hexa listing of the C lib, I noticed multiple variants (signed/unsigned), so even though I'm not using 32-bits anywhere in that method, and even though casting types under vbcc is very slow, I am going to try to cast it to see, if it changes anything. Note that it's not just that single one division in that method. Every single division in whole program (in other modules) is compiled like that (about 17 of them in total).

Comment: I have created 6 different versions (signed/unsigned of char/short int/int) of the following test method and all of them call the library function (jsr __ldivs) : 'void tmpdiv1 ()
{
 unsigned short int a,b,c;
 a = 100; b = 10;
 c = a/b;
}'  Interestingly, only unsigned int version called __ldivu, the other unsigned versions (char, short int) still called __ldivs

Comment: @3DCoder No matter what type you use, operator`/` promotes both operands to at least as wide as `int`/`unsigned int`, as is required by C standard. So it seems like VBCC failed to optimize it back to narrower types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [vbcc compiler system](http://server.owl.de/~frank/vbcc/docs/vbcc.pdf) manual by Volker Barthelmann:

> ### 4.1 Additional options
>
> This backend provides the following additional options:
>
> - `-cpu=n` Generate code for cpu n (e.g. -cpu=68020), default: 68000.
>
> ...
>
> ### 4.5 CPUs
>
> The values of `-cpu=n` have those effects: 
> ...
> `n>=68020`
>
> - 32bit multiplication/division/modulo is done with the mul?.l, div?.l and
>   div?l.l instructions.

The original 68000 CPU didn't have support for 32-bit divides, only 16-bit division, so by default vbcc doesn't generate 32-bit divide instructions.

Comment: But op updated in the comment that he was using 16bit inputs. However, with integer promotion, it's still depends on the smartness/aggressiveness of compiler optimization whether 32bit version or 16bit version is used. OP also mentioned in the comments that this compiler doesn't handle casting well, so I suspect integer promotion forces the compiler to use the 32bit version in the runtime library.

Comment: @user3528438 If `int` is 32 bits wide and not 16 then the compiler can't use the 16-bit divide instruction because of how the 68k handles overflow. If the result is is too big to fit into 16 bits then the divide instruction leaves the destination operand unchanged. If casts are used to try to force a 16-bit divide, the C standard still requires that result be calculated as if a 32-bit divide were used and the result then truncated to 16-bits.

Comment: That is true. However if both dividend and divisor are, or are casted to 16bits, then any decent compiler could detect the range and use 16 bit version instead. However, one edge case, `-32768/-1` may be difficult to handle.

Comment: I almost never use int, only short int everywhere (save for cases, where compiler does generate a faster code for 32-bit ints (weird, but true) - which is easy to confirm, as I constantly run a benchmark - the build/deploy/benchmark cycle runs under a minute - so I can benchmark every little change). As I mentioned above, i coded 6 versions of the simple test routine (with 6 different types, so there is no amiguity to the compiler) and all of them use library call to __ldivs, leading me to believe that under this compiler, it's impossible to avoid 32-bit division.

Comment: @3DCoder It's not impossible for it to avoid it using `__ldivs`.

Comment: @RossRidge Any idea how to force it to use 16bit division for the 16bit divisor/dividend then ? Optimization level (L0 vs L2) makes no difference. I do have another new trace, though. I removed the C library from the linker arguments, and the only linker error reported was, you probably guessed it right, '__ldivs'. So, the compiler is forcing that, not really the linker (which merely supplies the code for __ldivs).

Comment: @3DCoder Obviously it's the compiler, not the linker, that chooses whether to use a given CPU instruction or a library call instead. I didn't think that that was in question. If you want the vbcc compiler to generate the 16-bit divide instructions it looks like you'll have to modify it the source code of the compiler yourself: http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/release/vasm.tar.gz

Comment: That's not the answer I was hoping for, but at least I know it's impossible - because I do not consider the 'option' of rewriting the compiler an actual option as an alternative. But, it's of critical importance to understand I hit the limits of the vbcc compiler (so, it's time to try to configure gcc's object format with the platform's linker), and it's not just the question of configuring it, so I'm going to accept this as an answer. Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your question *doesn't even belong* here. You're asking about the workings of your compiler not the 68K cpu family.

> Since this is the most expensive instruction and it's in an inner loop, I really gotta experiment with tweaking the code to get the max performance of it.

Then you are already fighting windmills. Chosing an obscure C compiler while at the same time desiring top performance are conflicting goals.

If you really need MC68000 code compatibility, the choice of C is questionable. Since the 68000 has zero cache, store/load orgies that simple C compilers tend to produce en masse, have a huge performance impact. It lessens considerably for the higher members and may become invisible on the superscalar pipelined ones (erm, one; the 68060).

Switch to 68020 code model if target platform permits, and switch compiler if you're not satisfied with your current one.

Comment: I did not exactly chose the compiler, it was merely preinstalled in the whole platform package. I did, in past, try to get gcc working, and while I got the compilation part working, I ran into linker issues (missing platform libraries in the gcc-compatible format). But, it looks like I am going to have to switch compiler very soon. Can you recommend any proven, good 68000 C compiler ?

Comment: As for the platform, 68000 is fixed, as that's what the HW has. Thus, 68020 is out of the question, unfortunately.

Comment: As for the conflicting goals, that's actually the whole point - eventually this C code will be ported to ASM, but developing in C is easily an order of magnitude more productive (for debugging) than pure ASM.

Comment: @3DCoder If you're prototyping for later hand-optimizing, then why even worry about the compilers lack of optimizations? Any effort spend on C performance now would then go to wasted anyway? I'm not up to date what compilers are 'good', its been nearly two decades since my last 68k machine died.

Comment: That is because the hand-optimized ASM won't be written in 68k, but a different ASM. The HW platform has additional chips. This is basically an experiment how far can you go with C on 68k. The created demo will serve as a benchmark, what is possible using C on given platform, so the performance is very important. I have undergone multiple refactoring sessions to reach 60 fps and this particular area, with the division, is slowing things down. I have offset it with optimizations in different components,but would still prefer to be able to just the div.At least I know what is going on,